# What is the purpose of ping in SIGNALR (When transport is through WebSockets)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

```
ping?_=145265589222
ping?_=145265589223
ping?_=145265589224
ping?_=145265589225
```

I can't attach image, so showing browser ping result above.

Please tell me ping purpose and What if i set pinginterval=null, what will be its drawback or disadvantage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597468/use-of-signalr-ping-call-when-using-long-polling

Comment: Rism... It is explaining in long-polling. I want to know its purpose in websockets

Comment: The first line of the accepted answer for that question is : "The entire purpose of the /signalr/ping request is to keep ASP.NET sessions alive." That's your answer. So if you set it to null what do you think will happen?  Please search before you ask. With 9.4 million questions having been asked, its likely your question has already been answered as per the provided link.